# Use nm, strings and/or otool to find which library is wrongly using frameworks or methods

Tags: ios, linker, app-store

I had the same problem as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178533/app-store-submission-denied-ios-advertising-identifier).

The solution doesn't discuss however how `nm`, `strings` or `otool` can be used to search for offending code.

Let say that the offending code uses `ASIdentifierManager`'s `advertisingIdentifier` method from the `AdSupport.framework`.

- Concretely, how can binary libraries be searched with `nm`, `strings` or `otool`?
- How come there is no linker error even though `AdSupport.framework` is not part of the "Link Binary With libraries" build phase or linked through `OTHER_LDFLAGS`?

**Edit:**

After debugging many projects I realized that the best way to check if (and where) a framework is used is simply trying to build the target without linking the framework neither in your Build Phases or using `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

If the linker fails you'll have the name of the class and library responsible for using it.

If it passes then you can explain to Apple that the framework is not being used desire showing up on their string searches. This worked for our applications to get accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should find the lib your project use, like libxxx.a(libxxx.o). Then use nm/otool/strings,like

```
nm libxxx.a
```

Additional parameters and grep can be added for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging many projects I realized that the best way to check if (and where) a framework is used is simply trying to build the target without linking the framework neither in your Build Phases or using `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

If the linker fails you'll have the name of the class and library responsible for using it.

If it passes then you can explain to Apple that the framework is not being used desire showing up on their string searches. This worked for our applications to get accepted.