# Can't click "Ready to Upload Binary" due to IDFA

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am about to submit an update to my app and when I click "Ready to Upload Binary" I get the question:

*Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?*

Since AdMob uses it I select 'YES'. The image below shows what happends as I click 'Continue'.

The only problem is: **There is no way to select how the app uses IDFA!**

Does anyone know of how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: see this I'm sure It will solve IDFA rejection issue http://support.magplus.com/entries/40983886--Advertising-Identifier-Rejections-from-Apple

Comment: No, my problem is not being rejected but being able to activate "Ready to Upload Binary" and selecting IDFA. My app has not been rejected, I can't even upload the binary. Thanks though

Comment: I see, then I guess you should seek help from apple via contact in your developer account.

Comment: please check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178533/app-store-submission-denied-ios-advertising-identifier

Comment: Have read that one as well. But the problem is not that my app is rejected but that I cannot select that my app uses the IDFA and then upload a binary for review.

Comment: Try another browser maybe? Had issues with chrome in the past.

Comment: @VincentG Thank you!! That was indeed the problem. Used safari now and it works fine! Make that an answer and claim thy reward.

Comment: I would try in Safari, but unfortunately I set the IDFA question to "NO". Now validation is wrong (because I have iAD and Admob in my app). And there's no chance to set IDFA in "Waiting For Upload" state and I cannot reject binary in this state too. Deadlock.. Can sbody help?

Comment: @codedad try uploading a new binary based on a new Xcode project with the same app bundle and, after it has been uploaded, reject the binary so you can start the process again.

Comment: I see the same problem and I _am_ using Safari on my Mac! Seems like a broken web page. The validation won't let you through, but the extra field(s) aren't being shown when I select 'Yes'. Very frustrating.

Comment: Glad I helped, claiming my reward then :)

Comment: 1 week later it seems to me this validation is skipped by Apple from the ipa validation procedure since I was able to upload the same code without any modification. Now I'm waiting what will be the result of the Review Process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try another browser like Safari maybe? Had issues with chrome in the past.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly this problem, and it was due to my AdBlocker in Safari. Either disabling the AdBlocker or adding itunesconnect.com to the white list of the AdBlocker will solve the issue. Then when clicking YES on Advertising Identifier, you will get further options to select. I suspect this holds true for AdBlockers across all browsers, possibly down to the word Ad in the HTML and it being mistaken for an Ad popup.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I thought I was going crazy when the web form won't validate because of some fields I can't even see!

Answer (score 0):

If your AdBlocker is active in Safari you may briefly see a form flicker at the bottom of the page when you click "Continue". Saw it after a few tries. Switch off your adblocker in Safari preferences. Thanks Fuzzy Frog.