# Cancelling or changing iTunes Connect app update details

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

While creating a new version for my app, I set it up on iTunes Connect and filled in the binary details. During this process I added that I did not use add advertising in my app, however I do use advertising SDKs to track my conversion and other analytics.

Anyway, when validating my app, I get an error saying

> Improper Advertising Identifier Usage. Your app contains the
>   Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage
>   on the Prepare for Upload page on iTunes Connect.

How do I go back and change the Prepare for Upload details? Or a way of cancelling this update and starting again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to upload an empty app like in this tutorial and call it like your app.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBMXdfFqSYM

Then click on binary settings in iTunes Connect and click on "reject binary".
After that you can reenter the IDFA section on the "prepare for upload" page.

This is a workaround. Apple has to fix this problem in the future.

Comment: Argh, how rubbish! Thanks for the response...your workaround worked.

Comment: does anybody know if there's a way to request this change made to Apple?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979151/improper-advertising-identifier-idfa-usage), the only way to go back to start again is to upload an empty Xcode project (without any reference to IDFA) using the same bundle ID and, after it has been uploaded, reject the binary.

You can then restart the process, mark IDFA as used, and upload the correct project.

However, notice that if you do not use IDFA for actually displaying ads, your app could be rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I acidentally answered the IDFA question with "NO" (I'm using ADMOB) so I read about uploading an empty binary....

To bypass this:
My solution was to upload a binary with the (wrong) "**IOS Developer**" code signing identity.
The app was rejected automatically within minutes.
Then I answered the IDFA questions with:
YES, Serve advertisments within the app and checked the "Ad Limit Tracking" checkbox
And uploaded a "**iOS Distribution**" code signed binary to the store