# Error Submitting app to App store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, release, idfa

It give me an error but i'm not using anything related to Adv. ???

Is there is anyway can let me know if one of my library using it ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [improper advertising identifier \[IDFA\] usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979151/improper-advertising-identifier-idfa-usage)

Comment: @jojo suddenly it is work , without doing anything :D just keep hitting the submit button :P

Answer (score 0):

> You can upload any application with the same bundleID.
>
> When you've done uploading, you can reject binary and next time you
>   change status to Ready to Upload, don't forget check [IDFA].

Comment: nah , just kept hitting submit button until it work :P