# My app was rejected for using "Advertising Identifier"

Tags: ios, submit, iad, ads, identifier

My app was rejected for using advertising identifier, but I am not using any advertising identifier in my app.
I've checked my code and there is no advertising identifier, I am not even using the Ad support framework.

Yes, my app serves ads but I am using only the iAd framework to serve ads in my app and it's working perfectly fine, and I am not using any third party SDK.

In my first attempt to upload my app to the App Store, I've ticked YES to "***Does this app use Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?***".

Now I am resubmitting my app to the App Store, so I want to know - which option should I tick in the "***Does this app use Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?***" section?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge and time.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178533/app-store-submission-denied-ios-advertising-identifier

Comment: but this answer is accepted if we are using third party SDK like, AdMob, and i not using any third party SDK, i am using only iAd to serve ads in my app.

Answer (score 12):

I've found the answer myself.

From my personal experience, if you'r using only iAds to serve ads in you app and you'r not using any third party libraries like Admob or Facebook, then you need to check to "**NO**" on ***Does this app use Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?***, because iAd Framework did not use IDFA.

I've already submitted my game using this same procedure and now my app is live on app store [**Alius**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alius/id905738720?ls=1&mt=8) and receiving ads successfully (It may take up to 24hr to get ads on your app).

And, now i am going to add Interstitial ad by AdMob to my game and i think now i need to check to **YES** on Identifier Section in iTunes. I will update my answer as soon as i pass this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Seems iAD.framework uses IDFA. If our apps serve ads we always check "Does this app use Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?" ob submission

Comment: So,if i need to check to yes option, where i can find Advertising Identifier in my app, where it is located and even there is no property for setting up Advertising identifier. I am really confused.

Comment: In my case this not true, because my app is live and getting iAds, and i didn't check to yes on Advertising Identifier.